# 1045 PHPMyAdmin error using GAE

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, phpmyadmin, google-cloud-sql

**Summary:**
When attempting to log into PHPMyAdmin, which is running on GAE, I continuously receive MySQL 1045 error.

**Suspected issue:**
I believe I don't have the PHPMyAdmin environment connected to CloudSQL correctly, but I'm not exactly sure how to fix it.

**Files:**

**app.yaml** - The original version that was used in the tutorial didn't work, but I found another that allows me to load the page. Here's the working one.

```
application: appname
version: phpmyadmin
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: phpMyAdmin/\1
  upload: phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: phpMyAdmin/\1
  upload: phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: phpMyAdmin/\1
  upload: phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: phpMyAdmin/\1
  upload: phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  application_readable: true

- url: /phpMyAdmin/(.*\.(php$))
  script: phpMyAdmin/\1
  login: admin

- url: /(.*\.(php$))
  script: phpMyAdmin/\1
  login: admin

- url: /(.+)
  script: phpMyAdmin/index.php
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: phpMyAdmin/index.php
  login: admin
```

**config.inc.php -** I've made as little edits to this as possible.

```
/*
 * Servers configuration
 */
$i = 0;
$host = '/cloudsql/gae-project-name:appname';
$type = 'socket';

/*
 * First server
 */
$i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['username'] = 'root';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'thepassword';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = $host;
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = $type;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;


//The bottom of the file
$cfg['McryptDisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 60;
$cfg['CheckConfigurationPermissions'] = false;
```

**GAE:**
From what I can tell, the app has been whitelisted in GAE. It should have access to the CloudSQL instance. I've reset the password numerous times and I'm sure it matches in both locations.

**Background:**
I'm extremely new to GAE. There's a ton that I still don't understand about GAE, but I've followed some basic tutorials to get PHPMyAdmin loaded as a version of my application. The original tutorial ([here](https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/05/26/setting-up-phpmyadmin-on-app-engine/)) left me without the ability to see the PHPMyAdmin page at all. After some googling I discovered that I needed to change some of the app.yaml settings around. The page is now running, but I am unable to log into PHPMyAdmin at all.

In the past I've used things like WAMP and XAMPP to run MySQL. I've always had a GUI available to me in the past for troubleshooting things like this. I'm also really only familiar with MySQL interactions via PHPMyAdmin, so I'm kind of lost without it.

I'll provide anything you might need to help me understand where the issue is. Just let me know what you might need.

Comment: have you tried with only root as user and leaving the password empty, even if you set one in your CloudSQL instance? That's the way it works in Wordpress on GAE.

Comment: I just tried it. Doesn't seem to have made a difference. I'll keep that in mind as I look for the answer, though.

Comment: There is a tutorial on how to set this up: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/phpmyadmin-on-app-engine